# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' Form Validation Angular 7

Tags: angular

I know there are many possible answers for this kind of problem, but I can't fix it in my context. I'm following this tutorial to have a nice validation but it's for a old Angular version:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/validating-reactive-forms-with-default-and-custom-form-field-validators-in-angular-5586dc51c4ae

Now I get the error: `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'` for the `control.controls` property. I copied the exact things from the tutorial just renamed something. How to reach the same value that `control.controls` gives?

```
@Injectable()
export class FormService {

  // get all values of the formGroup, loop over them
  // then mark each field as touched
  public markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
      control.markAsTouched();

      if (control.controls) {
          control.controls.forEach(c => this.markFormGroupTouched(c));
      }
    });
  }
```

In my component.ts:

```
public buildForm() {
      this.registerForm = this.form.group({
        firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), CustomValidators.validateCharacters]],
        lastname: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.validateCharacters]],
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required]],
      });
```

How to change it to get your FormControls instead of my building here.

Version: Angular 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Typescript warning which is telling its useless to check `controls` property on `AbstractControl` (default) if AbstractControl doesn't hold any such prop.

Do this instead:

```
public markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
        control.markAsTouched();

        if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
            // if its a FormGroup then just call the method recursively
            this.markFormGroupTouched(control)
        }
    });
}
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqxdrj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: This gives me for the c in markFormGroupTouched `Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormGroup'.
  Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.`

Comment: @CptDayDreamer Check my edit if it works, I haven't gone through the article you have mentioned, but probably this should work.

Comment: Ehm doesn't work. You did a mistake in the edit? c is declared nowhere now.

Comment: @CptDayDreamer Right, send `control` instead of `c`

Comment: Hello. Please try `if (control.controls) {
          (control as FormGroup).controls.forEach(c => this.markFormGroupTouched(c));
      }`

Comment: @xyz it doesn't even go in the if-statement when I put a console.log() there and for mullisS thats the same problem like at the beginning

Comment: @CptDayDreamer I have added a stackblitz example in the answer, please see what I am missing there (coz it works in my case), create your own example and give the link

Comment: @xyz It doesn't work because forEach always gives me an array of AbstractControl: `(method) Array<AbstractControl>.forEach(callbackfn: (value: AbstractControl, index: number, array: AbstractControl[]) => void, thisArg?: any): void`

Comment: @CptDayDreamer Thats what is inferred typescript definitions but while looping through the "form controls" you get actual controls instead of Abstract Control. Was it not clear by the example I added?

Comment: @CptDayDreamer See this link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqbuxh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts . It works (I didn't have the custom validator so I didn't use one but you should get the idea, if not, then please replicate it the way I am doing)

Comment: @CptDayDreamer It won't go under the `if()` block in your code coz none of your form controls are a FormGroup themselves, if there will be one then it will go in the `if` block, just like the example added in the answer

Comment: @xyz I don't know what you mean. I've added a `new FormControl()` to my `buildForm()` if you meant this but it was the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191025/discussion-between-xyz-and-cptdaydreamer).